# Python error using Panda AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'asType'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm following a pluralsight course to learn Python data manipulation, and have an error in the first module! I'm using Jupyter Notebooks, with Python 3.7 and Pandas 1.0.1. Can anyone help please?

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('artwork_sample.csv')

data.dtypes
```

Returns:

```
id                      int64
accession_number       object
artist                 object
artistRole             object
artistId                int64
title                  object
dateText               object
medium                 object
creditLine             object
year                  float64
acquisitionYear         int64
dimensions             object
width                   int64
height                  int64
depth                 float64
units                  object
inscription           float64
thumbnailCopyright    float64
thumbnailUrl           object
url                    object
dtype: object
```

then

```
data.acquisitionYear.asType(float)
```

Produces this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-9daf408c9065> in <module>
----> 1 data.acquisitionYear.asType(float)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5272             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5273                 return self[name]
-> 5274             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5275 
   5276     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'asType'
```

Comment: It is typo `asType` - need `astype`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html
 Looks like a type of uppercase in asType
I looked for the uppercase and could not find it.